# Is it fine to have logging in golang test? Or is it a practice to not have logging in test?

Tags: testing, go, integration-testing

Is it fine to have logging in golang test? Or is it a practice to not have logging in test?

My test currently looks something like this. I am not sure if I am doing it right and is need of advise for the best practice to do test in golang. This is an integration test btw.

The log concern is mostly at the initialization step TestMain where the input is *testing.M that does not have log function.

```
var testDB *DB

func clearTable(name string) {
        var err error
        _, err = testDB.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("DELETE FROM %s", name))
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("[FATA] Failed to clear a table in database. name=%q err=%q", name, err)
        }
        _, err = testDB.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("ALTER SEQUENCE %s_id_seq RESTART WITH 1", name))
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("[FATA] Failed to reset ID sequence of a table in database. name=%q err=%q", name, err)
        }
}

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
        var err error
        testDB, err = NewDB(fmt.Sprintf("dbname=%s sslmode=disable", testDBName))
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("[FATA] Failed to initialize test database. dbName=%q err=%q", testDBName, err)
        }
        defer testDB.Close()
        code := m.Run()
        clearTable("worker")
        os.Exit(code)
}

func TestCreateWorker(t *testing.T) {
        clearTable("worker")

        createdWorkers := make(map[int]*Worker, 10)
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
                username := strings.Join([]string{"worker", strconv.Itoa(i)}, "")
                email := strings.Join([]string{username, "@gmail.com"}, "")
                passwordHash := strings.Join([]string{username, "PasswordHash"}, "")
                worker := Worker {
                        Username: username, 
                        Email: email,
                        PasswordHash: passwordHash,
                }
                err := testDB.CreateWorker(&worker)
                if err != nil {
                        t.Errorf("[ERRO] Failed to create a new worker in database. username=%q email=%q passwordHash=%q err=%q", username, email, passwordHash, err)
                }
                createdWorkers[i+1] = &worker
        }

        rows, err := testDB.Query("SELECT * FROM worker")
        if err != nil {
                t.Errorf("[ERRO] Failed to get all workers from database. err=%q", err)
        }
        defer rows.Close()
        for rows.Next() {
                returnedWorker := new(Worker)
                err := rows.Scan(&returnedWorker.ID, &returnedWorker.Username, &returnedWorker.Email, &returnedWorker.PasswordHash, &returnedWorker.CreatedAt)
                if err != nil {
                        t.Errorf("[ERRO] Failed to scan returned row into worker struct. err=%q", err)
                }
                createdWorker := createdWorkers[returnedWorker.ID]
                if !reflect.DeepEqual(&createdWorker, &returnedWorker) {
                        t.Errorf("[ERRO] Worker created in database and worker returned from database are different. createdWorker=%v returnedWorker=%v", createdWorker, returnedWorker)
                }
        }
}
```

Any good Golang github repo that does good logging to learn from?

Comment: The standard approach would be to use a configurable logger (i.e. probably not the standard library's `log` package), and for tests, configure logs to be discarded.

Comment: You may use `Log` or `Logf` function in `testing.T` struct - https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Log

Comment: Yes but test log has to be tied to testing.T which means I can't use it in clearTable() in my code.

Comment: You should never call log.Fatal in tests. Instead, pass a *testing.T to clearTable and fail the test.

Comment: @Peter But clearTable is just a helper function. It is not a test function. Should I pass *testing.T to helper function too? I am puzzled with how I am supposed to do this.

Comment: Yes, you should pass *testing.T to helper functions. It's just a value, nothing special at all.

Comment: Only if it's a helper function *for tests*. Any code that's used outside of tests should not reference the `testing` package.

Comment: Also there's no particular reason not to log in tests. It will be omitted in results unless `-v` is passed. If you find logging in tests to be a problem, then find a way to omit it; otherwise, you may as well leave it in. It is often useful in troubleshooting failing tests.

Comment: @Peter What about the logging in TestMain? I can't pass *testing.T to TestMain?

Comment: @Adrian I am not saying it is a problem. Just wondering what is the best practice?

Comment: "Best practice" is not a singular thing, and it's a matter of opinion, which makes it off topic for SO.

Answer (score 2):

Logging in tests is perfectly fine; that's why *testing.T has the Log and Logf methods.

Instead of calling log.Fatalf you should pass the testing structs to your helper function and let tests fail:

```
func clearTable(t *testing.T, name string) {
    t.Helper() // optional; identifies our caller as the culprit if test fails

    _, err := testDB.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("DELETE FROM %s", name))
    if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("[FATA] Failed to clear a table in database. name=%q err=%q", name, err)
    }
    _, err = testDB.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("ALTER SEQUENCE %s_id_seq RESTART WITH 1", name))
    if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("[FATA] Failed to reset ID sequence of a table in database. name=%q err=%q", name, err)
    }
}
```

As you already mentioned in the comments, this does not work for the TestMain function.

You should avoid defining TestMain, it is rarely necessary. Instead, call setup and teardown functions in each test. This makes tests self-contained and it is much easier to understand what is going on.

```
func TestCreateWorker(t *testing.T) {
    clearTable(t, "worker")
    defer clearTable(t, "worker")

    // test follows
}
```

Aside: think long and hard about whether you even want to call clearTable after each test. It is redundant with the first call, destroys all evidence of a failed test, and makes debugging harder.

If you want to keep your TestMain around, define a different helper function that does not depend on testing.T.

Comment: what do you mean by "It is redundant with the first call, destroys all evidence of a failed test,"?

Comment: @user136266, if a test fails, you usually don't want to destroy the test data. There is no point in emptying the worker table after a test if you also do it before the test.

Comment: How else show I initialize the connection to database if I don't have TestMain? just connect independently in each function?

Comment: This is what I prefer, yes. Again, tests are ideally self-contained and not spread out over multiple functions without explicit calls (which may even end up in different files).